# How to pause play and stop audio file Streaming From parse.com (android)?

Tags: java, android, audio, parse-platform

I am trying to play audio in my app from parse.com. I'm able to start and play the Media file but cant pause and stop it. Here is the code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Table");
query.getInBackground(ObjId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
public void done(ParseObject recording, com.parse.ParseException e) {
    if (e != null) { 
       //do nothing
    }
    else {
        ParseFile audioFile = recording.getParseFile("Audio"); 
        String audioFileURL = audioFile.getUrl();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFileURL);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
              //mediaPlayer.start();
           mediaPlayer.start();

          finalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
          startTime = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not playing a live stream, the file plays after the object is downloaded as you're setting up the action inside the

`public void done(ParseObject recording, com.parse.ParseException e)`

and this method is executed in another thread which complicates the situation a a lot, you should get the file first with:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Table");
ParseObject obj = query.getFirst()
ParseFile audioFile = obj.getParseFile("Audio"); 
        String audioFileURL = audioFile.getUrl();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

And then implement your other features.